# Why can't I call a Static method from another class which contains a Toast?

Tags: android, static-methods

Before posting this I did my research, but I am struggling to understand exactly what the issue is. So here is my method in class 1:

```
public static void scan() {
    for( int j=0; j< objarray.size();j++)
    {

        locationB.setLatitude(objarray.get(j).getlat());
        locationB.setLongitude(objarray.get(j).getlon());

        float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        if((distance < 600)&&(distance > 0.0) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You can go to" +objarray.get(j).gettitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }

    }
```

Everything in this method is Static, and the only thing giving me an error is the Toast.makeText call. Do I need to pass something to class1 which contains the scan method?

Like this:

```
Class1.Scan(something);
```

I think this may have something to do with the getApplicationContext() within the Toast, but I am unsure exactly what I need to do in order to fix this problem. Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: What is your error msg exactly?please post you logcat so we can help.

Comment: If its a `NullhPointer` exception then I would say `objarray.get(j).gettitle()` this is not static also you are wrong by using `getApplicationContext` try passing the current activity's context to the Toast rather.

Comment: As a few of the answers have implied, even though you say "everything in this method is static" this clearly is not the case. `getApplicationContext()` is not. While some of the answers below address your immediate problem, consider that [static methods are often an indicator of deeper problems in the design](http://www.benday.com/2010/03/15/article-static-methods-are-a-code-smell/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to pass something to class1 which contains the scan method?

Yes, you will need to pass current Activity context to `Scan` method  for showing Toast instead of calling directly  `getApplicationContext()` method in `Class1` (from non Activity class). change  Scan method as :

```
public static void Scan(Context context) {
   //...your code here....
    Toast.makeText(context,"You can go to"  
                  +objarray.get(j).gettitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }
```

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense, thank you! So what would the method call look like in class two, like this: Class1.Scan(Context context); Thanks!!

Comment: @deucalion0 : call Scan method from Class2 as : `Class1.Scan(getApplicationContext());` or if class `Class2` is an Activity then `Class1.Scan(Class2.this);`

Comment: Thanks for your help, class2 extends BroadCastReceiver and when I use Class1.Scan(getApplicationContext()) I get this error "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type ProximityIntentReceiver". Any idea why? Thank you!

Comment: @deucalion0 : if class2 extends BroadCastReceiver  then you have context as first parameter in onRecive method ? just pass it as `Class1.Scan(context)` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: That fixed it now I can call my method successfully! Thank you so very much for your help with this!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the application context to the method? `Class1.Scan(getApplicationContext())`

```
public static void scan(Context context) {
    for( int j=0; j< objarray.size();j++)
    {

        locationB.setLatitude(objarray.get(j).getlat());
        locationB.setLongitude(objarray.get(j).getlon());

        float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

        if((distance < 600)&&(distance > 0.0) )
        {
            Toast.makeText(context,"You can go to" +objarray.get(j).gettitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }

    }
```

Comment: This is what I am trying now but I get the error: "The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type ProximityIntentReceiver"